# missing FROM-clause entry for table when joining tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to join two tables and followed every step but I keep getting this error "missing FROM-clause entry for table "turbocharger". I have two tables: turbocharger and engine. 
 This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Engine"
FULL OUTER JOIN "Turbocharger" ON Turbocharger.Manufacturer_ID = Engine.Manufacturer_ID;
```

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_name and then suddenly that problem goes away just on its onw

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that you've created your table with quotes (create table "Turbocharger")
In this case PostgreSQL will always want to access this table with quoutes because name became case-sensitive.
So you need this

```
SELECT * FROM "Engine" FULL OUTER JOIN "Turbocharger" ON "Turbocharger".Manufacturer_ID = "Engine".Manufacturer_ID;
```

but I recommend use aliases

```
SELECT * FROM "Engine" e FULL OUTER JOIN "Turbocharger" t ON t.Manufacturer_ID = e.Manufacturer_ID;
```

HTH

Comment: ok, it didn't work then I realized I used quotes on the columns too so I had to add quotes as well to the Keys. But when I try to add PK's it would pop the same error but in the select section